# При запуске приложение появляется в диспетчере задач и через секунду исчезает

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Написал приложение на Delphi 7, работающее с БД. При запуске на другом компьютере Project.exe появляется в диспетчере задач и буквально через секунду исчезает из него.

Можно ли мое приложение запустить на другом компьютере, на котором не установлена Delphi, и если можно, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему вашей программе не хватает установленного BDE (Borland Database Engine).

Для установки BDE есть два варианта:

1. Ручная установка.
2. С помощью создания инсталятора для программы.

**Ручной режим**

Идем в `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Borland Shared\BDE`, берем файл bdeinst.cab, извлекаем из него (rar'ом или zip'ом) файл bdeinst.dll.

На компьютере, где нужно запускать нашу программу открываем Command Prompt и пишем:

```
regsvr32 bdinst.dll
```

запустится установка BDE.
Далее если нужно в BDE Administrator'е указать используемые алиасы.

**С помощью инсталятора**

Ставим из дистрибутива Delphi InstalShield Express, создаем проект, добавляем свои файлы, далее открываем в дереве Specify Application Data-> Objects/Merge Modules, находим в списке модулей BDE, ставим галку, указываем путь к существующему файлу конфигурации или создаем новый... далее см. справку по InstalShield'у...

Аналогично можно воспользоваться InnoSetup'ом или другими "Borland-certified installation program".

Comment: Еще может быть использование ODBC? Поправьте если я не прав.

Comment: TTable в любом случае будет работать через BDE. BDE дает возможность работать с любым драйвером (см. закладку Configuration -> drivers), который описан как Native или ODBC, но запросы идут через BDE в любом случае.

Если в программе подключение к базе без использования компонента TDatabase, просто указанием пути, то будет использован нативный драйвер для доступа к paradox'у.

Comment: Если используется TDatabase, то в нем можно указать драйвер (native или odbc) или алиас (который создан в BDE administrator'е или импортирован из ODBC конфигурации). И соответственно если выбрать odbcшный драйвер или алиас с odbcшным драйвером, то возникнет еще одна зависимость - от этого драйвера. Зависимость дополнительная, да.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно! *.EXE файл - это файл-исполнитель, который может запуститься на всех операционных системах семейства Windows. Тут вопрос в другом: не требует ли приложение, работающее с определенной СУБД, каких-нибудь дополнительных библиотек?

**P.S** Вы, случайно, не с SQL-сервером работаете( Mysql, MSSql )?

Comment: нет,SQL не использую. есть база на Paradox7 и форма с парой DBGrid, таблицы связаны через masterSource, и отчет QReport. При запуске на другом компе, никаких ошибок, просто *.exe файл помещается в диспетчер задач и тут же исчезает оттуда

Comment: А на вашем компьютере все нормально работает?

Comment: Да, на моём без проблем запускается

Comment: А ошибки какие-нибудь выдает?

Comment: Ошибок нет, Ни на компьютере с делфи, ни на том что без него.

Comment: Вообщем, она так себя начинает вести, после того как, значение Active присвоить True, в компоненте Ttable

Comment: ох...даже не знаю. Нет ошибок, все работает на одном компьютере нормально...как-то это неправдоподобно звучит, честно. Может это вы чего-то не то намутили, попробуйте просмотреть весь свой код.